# Location Accuracy Plugin Nothing happens when I call the function

Tags: location, ionic3

I built the following code in my phone,no errors anywhere,But when I click on the button i need to check either device location enable or not but using below code nothing happens i am using android 7.0 version can some one help me please and i just follow this link How to programatically enable and disable GPS in Ionic Framework or Cordova

```
start(){
    this.locationAccuracy.canRequest().then((canRequest: boolean) => {
      if(canRequest) {
        this.locationAccuracy.request(this.locationAccuracy.REQUEST_PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY).then(() => {
            console.log('Request successful.')
          },
          error => {
            console.log('Error requesting location permissions', error)
          }
        );
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Try to add catch to your outer promise... instead of sending a callback to the inner one. Also use `this.platform.ready().then(()=>{})`

Comment: Hi @suraj Rao i have one doubt your free?

Comment: not exactly.. browse SO along with work. If you have another issue, suggest creating another post

Answer (score 1):

Below code resolved my issue

```
this.platform.ready().then((readySource) => {

      this.diagnostic.isLocationEnabled().then(
        (isAvailable) => {
          console.log('Is available? ' + isAvailable);
          alert('Is available? ' + isAvailable);
        }).catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
          alert(JSON.stringify(e));
        });

    });
```